# Git-log is it possible to ignore removals?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

I am attempting to make a change log for my colleagues to detail issues I've resolved in a project, however the command I'm using (`git log -p -2`) is producing a 180MB output text-file due to the number of removals from the system I've made. I'm only interested in retaining the diff output for changed files, is there any way of going about this? I've searched through the manual at length for both `git-log` and `git-diff` but aside from `--ignore-all-space` I've not found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` has the option `-D`/`--irreversible-delete`. This just shows that a file was deleted instead of showing all the contents which were deleted from that file.

Comment: That's perfect thanks, I knew I'd have missed something silly; 180MB down to a mere 67MB!